# Add a new columns to a dataframe by transposing rows of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add new columns to a dataframe by transposing rows of another dataframe.

Here is my `DF1`:

```
ID1  Value1  Value2
11   xxx      yyy
12   aaa      bbb
```

Here is `DF2`:

```
Index ID2   KEY     VALUE
1     123   ID1     11
2     123   FOLDER  folder1
3     123   FILE    file1
4     456   ID1     12
5     456   FOLDER  folder2
6     456   FILE    file2
7     456   FOLDER  folder3
8     456   FILE    file3
```

Note that `ID2` `456` has duplicate `KEY`'s.

I want to ignore all duplicate keys and pick the values for last `KEY`'s (with highest value of `Index`).

What I want:

1. Look for the `KEY` = `ID1` in `DF2`.
2. Transpose all the remaining keys with identical `ID2`

Output:

```
ID1  Value1  Value2  FOLDER   FILE
11   xxx      yyy    folder1  file1
12   aaa      bbb    folder3  file3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first do a [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe), then a [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101):

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(keep='last', subset=['ID2', 'KEY']).pivot(index='ID2', columns='KEY', values='VALUE').astype({'ID2': int}))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   ID1 Value1 Value2   FILE   FOLDER
0   11    xxx    yyy  file1  folder1
1   12    aaa    bbb  file3  folder3
```

Comment: Thank you @Richardec for the answer. But, I just noticed that my DF2 has duplicate KEY's. 
Meaning, I have 2 values of FOLDERNAME for ID2 = 456 in above example.
Due to this, I'm getting `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` error. How can I take last value of the KEY?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of such a case in the question? Just so that it's easier for me to understand.

Comment: @Shital done. Check now :)

Comment: The duplicate key error is gone but now I'm getting this error - `KeyError: "Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument. 'ID1' not found in columns."`

Comment: Weird. Try now.

Comment: Sorry, My bad. There was problem in my dataframe. Your solution works perfectly. Accepting as right answer.